# Getting Typescript Error while adding object to array using useState in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Result type prop is defined as follows. CalendarProp, ContactProp,... are predefined and all have different types.

```
type ResultProp =
    | { type: "calendar", data: CalendarProp }
    | { type: "contact", data: ContactProp }
    | { type: "dropbox", data: DropboxProp }
    | { type: "slack", data: SlackProp }
    | { type: "tweet", data: TweetProp }
```

Calendar Prop

```
interface CalendarProp {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    invitees: string,
    date: string,
    matching_terms: Array<string>
}
```

ContactProp type

```
interface ContactProp {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    company: string,
    emails: Array<string>,
    phones: Array<string>,
    last_contact: string,
    matching_terms: Array<string>
}
```

All the props have a different type.
Component maintaining a result array is defined below. I am getting Typescript error while adding object to result array using useState hook.
Here calendarData.calendar, ... is an array of json object.

```
const SearchResults: React.FC<QueryProp> = (props) => {
    const query = props.query;
    const [result, setResult] = useState<Array<ResultProp>>([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (query.length > 0){
            const files = [
                {
                    type: "calendar",
                    data: calendarData.calendar
                },
                {
                    type: "contact",
                    data: contactData.contacts
                }, 
                {
                    type: "dropbox",
                    data: dropboxData.dropbox
                },
                {
                    type: "slack",
                    data: slackData.slack
                },
                {
                    type: "tweet",
                    data: tweetData.tweet
                }
            ];

            for(const file of files){
                for(const d of file.data){
                    if (d.matching_terms.includes(query)) {
                        switch(file.type) {
                            case "calendar":
                                setResult([...result, { type: "calendar", data: d }]); // Error here
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return () => {
            setResult([]);
        }
    }, [query])

    return (
        <div className="search-results">
            {/* {result.map((r, index) => {
                return <Cardview key={index} {...r} />
            })} */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
Argument of type '({ type: "contact"; data: ContactProp; } | { type: "dropbox"; data: DropboxProp; } | { type: "slack"; data: SlackProp; } | { type: "tweet"; data: TweetProp; } | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<ResultProp[]>'.
  Type '({ type: "contact"; data: ContactProp; } | { type: "dropbox"; data: DropboxProp; } | { type: "slack"; data: SlackProp; } | { type: "tweet"; data: TweetProp; } | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type 'ResultProp[]'.
    Type '{ type: "calendar"; data: { id: string; title: string; invitees: string; matching_terms: string[]; date: string; } | { id: string; name: string; company: string; emails: string[]; phones: string[]; matching_terms: string[]; last_contact: string; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ResultProp'.
      Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
        Type '{ id: string; title: string; invitees: string; matching_terms: string[]; date: string; } | { id: string; name: string; company: string; emails: string[]; phones: string[]; matching_terms: string[]; last_contact: string; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'CalendarProp'.
          Type '{ id: string; name: string; company: string; emails: string[]; phones: string[]; matching_terms: string[]; last_contact: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'CalendarProp': title, invitees, date
```

Comment: Can you post what `CalendarProp` and the others look like plus what shape `calendarData.calendar` etc have?

Comment: the files in the `files` array don't have a narrowable discriminant, `type` is just a `string`. Also, Based on the types you've added, the inner loop doesn't make sense and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you test that `file` coming from `files` match the `calendar` type. But you never said to TypeScript the type of `files`. It's not sure for him what `d` really is so it can be `CalendarProp` or `ContactProp` or... You have 2 solutions to fix that:

1. Declare the type of `files`:

```js
const files: ResultProp[] = [
  ...
```

In this case, if `file.type` is `"calendar"`, then TypeScript can deduce that `data` is of type `CalendarProp`.

---

2. Cast the value of `d` to `CalendarProp`:

```js
setResult([...result, { type: "calendar", data: d as CalendarProp }]);
```